# Deploying Lambdas that output to S3, or read from databases in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have a step function of 4 lambdas that read from databases, and write to S3 buckets. Now, all the db/s3 specific code is in the lambdas itself, all I did was attach invoke and role policies to the lambda. There are no "S3" or "DB" resources I'm making/adding in Terraform. My question is, would that be a problem? Would I have to specifically add some rules about S3/DB, and/or more lines in my deployment, or do I just let the lambda's take care of it, since they already include all the connection to those AWS resources?

Comment: It should be fine. It sounds a bit like you are in search of a problem that doesn't exist. I suggest trying it first and coming back here if you run into an actual, concrete problem.

Comment: It applied and went well, I'll leave it to devs to check it. Thanks!